# getting response undefined in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, subscribe

I want to fetch this data from rest api but when i tried to console.log(response) i am getting undefined value.
what should i do ?
api is sending data and i have checked it in my network tab in developer tool.

```
getProductList() : Observable<Product[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<GetResponse>(this.baseUrl).pipe(
      map(response => response._embedded.products),
      tap((response) => console.log("Response:"+response))
    );
   } 

interface GetResponse{
    _embedded:{
      products: Product[];
    }
}
```

[JSON Data Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsRXz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to access Product?

```
map(response => response._embedded.product)
```

and interface

```
interface GetResponse{
    _embedded:{
      product: Product[];
    }
}
```